# PHP - Populate dropdown using table names from a database

Tags: php, mysql

I've tried everything, and I just can't do it. I need to create a dropdown using the name of the tables in a database. Please, give me some light. Thanks everyone!

```
    $str = "";
  $conn = connect_bd();

  $sql = "SHOW TABLES FROM $banco";
  $result = $conn->query($sql);
  if(!$result){
    $str = $str . "<option> Não foi possível fazer a consulta no banco. </option>";
  }

  while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc($result)){
    $str = $str . "ok";
  }
```

Comment: `SHOW TABLES FROM <database>`

Comment: Are you setting `$banco`?

Comment: @Blinkydamo yes, this is just a part of the code.

Comment: Try just `show tables`

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php $array = array( 'one','two','three' ); ?>

<select>
<?php foreach( $array as $key ) { ?>
  <option><?php echo $key; ?></option>
<?php } ?>
</select>
```

This is the basic idea, you loop through the array and for each item with the array echo out the value into an option for the select.

Comment: Yes, I did one using the column values, just like this one that you did, and it worked. The problem is that any of my "show tables from $dbname" are working, I can´t query this. I also tried mysql_list_tables($dbname), but still not working

Comment: show more of your code, it is going to be very difficult for people to help without seeing your code.

Comment: $str = "";
$conn = connect_bd();

  $sql = "SHOW TABLES FROM $banco";
  $result = $conn->query($sql);
  if(!$result){
    $str = $str . "<option> error </option>";
  }

  while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc($result)){
    $str = $str . "ok"; #this is just a test 
  }

Answer (score 0):

you can try this to get table names in a array

```
$result = mysql_query("show tables"); // run the query and assign the result to $result
$tables=array();
while($table = mysql_fetch_array($result)) { // go through each row that was returned in $result
    $tables[]=$table;                   
}

print_r($tables);
```

then you can use this `$tables` array to populate your dropdown